# Cannot resolve the symbol fragment_main

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i´ve started to learn developing android apps with **Android Studio** with an tutorial and now i´ve got a problem in my `MainActivityFragment`.

Here´s the code

```
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

The problem lies in: `return inflater.inflate(R.ayout.fragment_main, container, false)`

`fragment_main` is *red underlined* and **Android Studio** says:
  "`cannot resolve the Symbol"fragment_main`"

Comment: is `fragment_main.xml` in project layout folder is present ?

Comment: yes i have it in my layout folder

Comment: Can you post your XML file (fragment_main) or a picture of it?

Comment: yes...actually it looks like: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-29587417/Unbenannt.png.html

Comment: here is the xml file: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-29587443/Unbenannt.png.html

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `'l'`:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
// -----------------------^
```

And make sure that you have a `fragment_main.xml` layout file in your `res/layout` directory.

**EDIT:**

Change

```
import android.R;
```

to

```
import com.example.martin.myapplication.app.R; // or ...myapplication.R
```

Comment: yes i have it in my res/layout direcotry. and no i didnt miss the ´l´ .. it was just a mistake in the question :) actually i have: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

Comment: @M.Schneider please update your post with a screenshot of your project's view.

Comment: that's not a valid image path.

Comment: Have you tried both combinations ? `import com.example.martin.myapplication.app.R;` and `import com.example.martin.myapplication.R;`

Comment: Delete that `import`. Isn't *Android Studio* prompting you with an **import suggestion** ?

Comment: yes but i started with android studio 1 day ago so i actually dont know what to do with it....i deleted the import. and now i have: com.example.martin.myapplication.R;    now the whole phrase is red underlined

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the best I could think of; good luck solving your problem :)

Comment: @M.Schneider just keep digging, +1

Comment: i think i got it...i cleaned and rebuilded the project :)

Comment: & what was the correct import among those 2 that I've suggested to you ?

Comment: have you resolved your query or still stuck I have a solution for this

Comment: it was import com.example.martin.myapplication.app.R

Comment: Good for you @M.Schneider, please accept the answer then

Answer (score 0):

There is no values such as `R.ayout.something`

> return inflater.inflate(R.ayout.fragment_main, container, false)

Just make it `R.layout.fragment_main` , like

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Provided the layout resource **fragment_main.xml** exists in `res/layout/` folder, it should work fine.

Comment: i did, fragment_main is still red underlined :/ same problem